# Find longest length string in array of tuples

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of tuples `var label = [(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, v1: String, v2: String)]()` and would like to find the string of longest length in v1.

I could iterate through the array like this:

```
var maxlength = 0
var position = 0
for i in 0 ..< label.count {
   if label[i].v1.count > maxlength {
      maxlength = label[i].v1.count
      position = i
   }
}
print("longest string: \(maxlength) chars, at position \(position), is \(label[position].v1)")
```

but is there a more concise method?

Comment: Please stop adding tags to your question titles. There is a dedicated space for tags. Question title should describe the problem in one sentence so that people can find it more easily, but the tags are not needed there.

Comment: Ok.  I've added them because often, when I am looking for help, I often end up in posts made for other languages.  I  saw other people do this and like it because it helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `max(by:)` operator on your `label` array.

```swift
let longestString = label.max { $0.v1 < $1.v1}
```

Or a combination of `map` and `max`, as you're only interested in the longest string, not the tuple with the longest string value.

```swift
let longestString = label.map(\.v1).max()
```

---

For finding the position you have 2 options

`enumerated:`

```swift
let positionOfLongestString: Int? = label
  .map(\.v1)
  .enumerated() // converts array to a (offset: Index, element: String) tuple array
  .max { $0.element < $1.element }?
  .offset
```

`firstIndexOf`:

```swift
let positionOfLongestString: Int? = label
  .map(\.v1)
  .max()
  .flatMap { longestString in 
    label.firstIndex { $0.v1 == longestString }
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Is there a way to tell the position of that element?

Comment: Yes there is, you can use `enumerated` for this, or `firstIndexOf`. I'll update the answer.